# HTML5 Game Arcade - security

Tags: html, security, xss

I am looking in to creating a simple html5 game arcade where people can submit their games and then I host them.

The games will be running in the browser directly. They won't access any servers once the content has loaded. Much like the old school flash arcade sites (Miniclip etc). It won't be single player.

The content I am concerned about the games accessing primarily would be user session data for registered/ logged in users.

I'm wondering what the best way to secure these without auditing every line of submitted code?

At the moment I am thinking I should host the games on a different domain (likely a cdn) and then iframe them.

Would this work? Is there anything else I should do to make sure the games can't access information about users?

Comment: What will the games be? Client side code only?

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific - what information about users do you not want them accessing?  These games will be running in the user's browser, they'll have the same access to the user as any other page loaded in the browser would have.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the questions. I have added some additional details to the main post.

Essentially the games will be in the browser only, not multiplayer (at least not initially), and i am concerned about users accessing session data/ other user specific stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the content of an iframe from a different domain is not allowed to access the parent's DOM, there are still several ways in which the security of your users may be compromised by loading untrusted content on an iframe. 
For instance, the iframe can redirect to a non-safe site, serve malware or use some kind of phishing scheme such as showing a "session expired" message on the iframe together with a mock-up login form to steal your user's passwords. In all these cases, as the URL shown in the address bar is always that of your site, users are more likely to trust its contents and blame you if something goes wrong.
I don't know of any solution to automatically check whether or not a submitted code is malicious, and I would be very cautious about its effectiveness if you ever find one. Take for instance the phishing example. In that case there's nothing wrong with the code itself (as some games may have genuine log-in forms for its players), it is the context in which it's shown (as a mock-up of your real log-in form) what makes it malicious.

Comment: I think this would be an issue for any games portal though. I don't plan to allow open uploads, I'd contact developers of games I have seen and ask if they want to have their game hosted by me before putting it on the site. I realise this wouldn't stop malicious intent but it should reduce potential problems.

I do appreciate that anytime I put code on my site from an untrusted source that it could open me up to problem though.

I wonder if there's some way I can search for specific commands or block connections outside of the hosting domain so that they can't transfer data

Comment: Blacklisting is quite ineffective because there are countless possible malicious combinations of commands (which can be obfuscated).
Instead, you can try to run the code through some javascript malware detection software such as wepawet. I haven't tried it myself so I can only guess, but it's most likely better than implementing an ad-hoc detector yourself.

Comment: Serans - that's great, I hadn't heard of that before. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You're welcome! Just in case somewhere else is reading this, he/she might find useful to know that wepawet can also scan PDFs and Flash files, and it links every vulnerability/exposure it finds to the corresponding CVE page. BTW if you find my solution useful, please consider upvoting it ;)

Comment: unfortunately I can't upvote cos my reputation isn't high enough :(